# Detect if a key is the root of a loaded/mounted registry hive

Tags: c++, c, windows, registry

In a running Windows, how can I ascertain via a C/C++ program of my own if a certain key is the "mount point", i.e. root, for a registry hive?

Via [`RegLoadKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regloadkeyw) and the underlying NT native function (`ZwLoadKey` aka `NtLoadKey` from user mode) one can load/mount a hive.

Is there a way to figure out, just given the key (handle or path), if the key is the root or "mount point" of a registry hive?

To make it clear, I am aware that many a key in the `\Registry` (object manager namespace) is a subkey *inside* a loaded hive. But I am asking to find out about whether a particular key represents the *root* of a loaded hive. So I know the name of a key and I want to find out by any means Windows has to offer whether that key is the root of a loaded hive.

Bonus points for showing how to figure out the corresponding file path to the loaded hive on disk for a given key.

NB: I do not care if the Win32 API or NT native API is required to achieve this. I am just straight out looking for a way to achieve this feat.

Comment: Seriously, what exactly is too broad about a question like this? I mean, _really_?! How can I make it _any more specific_ when I am _literally_ asking for some - unknown to me - facility to test a _very specific_ condition? The fact that this question received a **to-the-point** answer is proof that this question is not at all too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists an indirect way to check this - call the undocumented NT native API function `ZwQueryOpenSubKeys`:

```
EXTERN_C
NTSYSCALLAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
ZwQueryOpenSubKeys(
    _In_ POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES TargetKey,
    _Out_ PULONG HandleCount
);
```

According to the following [line](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Config/ntapi.c#L4863) from the WRK code we can assume that in the case where the key is not the root cell, the APIs return `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. In case `STATUS_SUCCESS` returned this is the root cell of a hive. For other status codes we cannot tell if it is or isn't the root of a hive.

Example code:

```
enum { root, not_root, fail } IsRootCell(PCOBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
{
    ULONG  HandleCount;
    switch (NtQueryOpenSubKeys(poa, &HandleCount))
    {
    case STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return root;
    case STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER:
        return not_root;
    }

    return fail;
};
```